# Is it better to use generics or Object type for a static helper class in Java?

Tags: java, list, object, generics

I was writing a program the other day that required me to: get the frequency of a particular object inside an `ArrayList<String>`, remove all occurrences of a given item, etc., etc. not specified by the `List` interface. I decided to write my own helper class and wanted to make it as reusable as possible. I decided to specify `List` as the parameter type of the collection so I could use it for any class implementing the `List` interface. But these classes are usually defined using generics, and I did not know what class type the item to be removed would be. So I either had to define the static helper methods generically since a static class can not contain generic types explicitly, or define the class type of the object to be removed as `Object`. I implemented it in both ways, see below, but am wondering if there any benefits to using one over the other.

Some further questions on the topic:

1. Why am I able to work around the reference of a generic type in a static context by defining it in the method header rather than the class header?
2. When using this static method, why do I **not** have to declare the class Type in its usage? i.e. `ListTools_V2.getFrequencyOf(ArrayList<String> items, String s)` still works.

**Implementation using Object class type**

```
import java.util.List;

/** General utility class for performing frequently needed operations
    on any class implementing the List interface **/ 
public class ListTools {

    public static void removeAllOccurrences(List items, Object o) {
        while(items.contains(o)) {
            items.remove(o);
        }
    }

    public static int getFrequencyOf(List items, Object o) {
        int frequency = 0;
        for(Object item : items) {
            if(item.equals(o)) {
                frequency++;
            }
        }
        return frequency;
    }

}
```

**Implementation using generics**

```
import java.util.List;

/** General utility class for performing frequently needed operations
    on any class implementing the List interface. This implementation
    uses generics to maximize reusability. **/ 
public class ListTools_V2 {

    public static <E> void removeAllOccurrences(List<E> items, E o) {
        while(items.contains(o)) {
            items.remove(o);
        }
    }

    public static <E> int getFrequencyOf(List<E> items,E o) {
        int frequency = 0;
        for(E item : items) {
            if(item.equals(o)) {
                frequency++;
            }
        }
        return frequency;
    }

}
```

Comment: [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html) and [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html) are good reads.

Comment: dude, I hope I don't ruin your day: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object)

Comment: @jangroth Thank you for pointing that one out, but I'm still glad I implemented them myself. Definitely learning some basic principles throughout the process.

Answer (score 1):

Both operations operate on equality (`.equals()`) between the given object reference and the elements inside the list, and equality is not limited to objects of the same type, so you shouldn't restrict `o` to be the same type as the type parameter of the list.

However, raw types are bad, so you shouldn't use the raw type `List`. You should parameterize it with a wildcard when there is no need to constrain the type variable against anything:

```
public static void removeAllOccurrences(List<?> items, Object o)
public static int getFrequencyOf(List<?> items, Object o)
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic is better as it detects type related issues at compile time. 
During runtime "erasure" takes place and there is no "meaning" to generics. 
For example:

```
List apples = new ArrayList();
apples.add(new Apple());
apples.add(new Mango()); //compiles, but this is wrong
apples.add(new Chair()); //compiles, but this is wrong
```

You must of course be aware of all kinds of "pitfalls" of the generic mechanism.
Examples I can easily think of are: 
`List<Mango>` does not extend `List<Fruit>` , so you should use `List<? super Fruit>` or `List<? extends Fruit>` 
You cannot do something like :

```
T.getClassName()
```

Comment: As you may encounter runtime issues, if you're going to try to perform cast of retrieved objects , for example - accessing a list of apples, trying to get an object, cast it to Apple, and have ClassCastException as by mistake Mango was added. Such mistakes will be prevented at compile time if Generics are used.

Comment: There is no retrieval in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Generics is the recommended way of implementing such classes. They can be used to give some implicit information to your user (whoever uses this class).
For example:

```
List<Cat> cats = ...;
ListTools.removeAllOccurrences(cats, new Dog());
```

it is meaningless since, there cannot be any dogs inside a List of Cats. But user can execute this code and imagine that he has deleted some dogs from the List of cats.On the other hand generic version informs the user about this inappropriate call.

```
List<Cat> cats = ...;
ListTools_V2.removeAllOccurrences(cats, new Dog()); // Compile time error because it is pointless
```

Additionally there is a performance gain as well. If the List of Cats contains thousands of Cats, do you really want to search for that Dog inside a large number of Cat List? (*contains* method actually search the entire List) or do you simply want to avoid it at the compile time? ;)

Comment: "it is meaningless since, there cannot be any dogs inside a List of Cats." Not true. A `Dog` can be equal (as in `.equals()`) to a `Cat`, depending on how `Dog` and `Cat` are implemented, and it is equality that matters for removal.

Comment: Ya you are right. I have'nt provide the code of Cat and Dog with an assumption that they are totally two different classes.

Answer (score 0):

your getFrequencyOf() method body is essentially same in both the cases except in one case you are passing raw List and in another you are parameterizing it to accept any type.

1-

```
public static int getFrequencyOf(List items, Object o) {
        int frequency = 0;
        for(Object item : items) {
            if(item.equals(o)) {
                frequency++;
            }
        }
        return frequency;
    }
```

Here you List is a raw type. References to generic type List should be parameterized which, is not. But it is open for any type of List (Integer, Long, String etc.)

2-

```
public static <E> int getFrequencyOf(List<E> items,E o) {
        int frequency = 0;
        for(E item : items) {
            if(item.equals(o)) {
                frequency++;
            }
        }
        return frequency;
    }
```

Here you List is NOT a raw type. References to generic type List should be parameterized which, it is. And this as well is open for any type of List (Integer, Long, String etc.)